Looking for an Indian movie that I watched a long time ago as a kid
Its about a guy who lives with a bunch of kids and a guru. One day he finds a shiny yellow oval stone which grants him power. 
The antagonist(villain) had been searching for this stone for a long time. And he finds out that the protagonist(hero) has it. 
The reason the antagonist wants it is because this stone once a year or something if you take  it to a certain temple at the right time you can get a nectar in exchange for the stone which grants you immortality. 
So he kidnaps the kids and forces the protagonist to go the temple with a conch. When he gets to the temple the antagonist has to go through a series of trials and reach the end of the temple. 
He then places the stone on a pedestal that's designed like snake heads. And the stone becomes super enlarged. And he uses the conch to collect the nectar for immortality and gives it to the antagonist. He drinks it becomes immortal. 
The only way to stop the antagonist now is if the protagonist can get him to touch the enlarged stone. Because you can't get immortality and the stone. Its against the rules or something. 
They fight and eventually the hero forces the villain to touch the enlarged stone and this snake god or goddess comes for the villain killing him. Its just a bunch of giant snakes that come from nowhere and kill him.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing?Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

time frame, language, other description would be helpful

I don't know why this one is downvoted and voted to close. It clearly provides significant plot details.
